# Is there an elegant way to populate an area with RigidBody objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a penny pusher (like the game machines you find in arcades) game in Unity in my spare time and obviously that means I need to populate the shelf with coins so the player's spawned coins actually have function.

My issue is I haven't worked out how to spawn that many coins in an elegant way which won't either slow the game down with spawning so many objects at once or result in a lumped pile of coins rather than the neat spread I need.
I even tried speeding up the simulation by several times and dropping a pile of coins on the pushing shelf so they would "settle" before the player input was enabled. It didn't work.

So I ask if there's a good way to do this as part of the initialisation of the game and any Unity or C# function which would have the intended effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly it really does dependent. The problem is that your game **will** be lagging when you have to many physic interactions. So even if you spawned them without alot of physic interactions, once u move one coin it will start lagging.

I would look for an alternative way then physics to handle them. Maybe you can think of a more simple calculation you do your self where you have less interactions going on each frame.

That beeing said a way to spawn the coins would be to calculate a random position at a fixed height (max height) and then find out what the lowest point is where the coin can sit on (so it does not share space with another coin). Now place it there. Even better would be to calculate if it could actually be placed there without instanly falling.

I think the best way would be having predefined "Coin Towers" (prefabs of them) where you have like 10 variations and then place them at different positions but do not allow to spawn any "Coin Towers" on another one. This would result in less physic interactions when spawned too.

May be helpful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTz3LMQpvfA